# Laravel blade variable not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Heres the controller:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        return View::make('home', array('username' => 'Vaughan'));
    }
}
```

Here the home blade view:

```
{{ $username }}
```

Yet the view is outputting exactly this:

```
{{ $username }}
```

The variable is not being rendered. Could this be something to do with Apache or PHP?

Comment: Are other blade elements rendering?

Comment: I know it's unlikely, but does this view have the correct extension - `.blade.php`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to name your view with blade extension:

```
home.blade.php
```

That's all.